# index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2 coupled pendulum differential equations

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, differential-equations

I am fairly new to coding, and have to code some models in one of my classes. In this case, I have to model a coupled pendulum, which is a system of second order differential equations.

[image: Here are the two equations]

As viewed in class, I simplified the equations to a system of 4 first order differential equations, and tried implementing them in my code and solving them using solve_ivp. Here is the code I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.animation as animation

%matplotlib inline

g = 9.8
L = 2 #length of the pendulum in meters
k = 3
m1 = 2
m2 = 2

s = (20,20)
state = np.zeros(s)

def der_state(t, state):
        """compute the derivative of the given state"""
        der = np.zeros_like(state)
        der[0] = state[1]
        der[1] = (-(g/L)*np.sin(state[0]))-((k/m1)*((np.sin(state[0])-(np.sin(state[2])))))
        der[2] = state[3]
        der[3] = (-(g/L)*np.sin(state[0]))-((k/m2)*((np.sin(state[2])-(np.sin(state[1])))))
        return der

tf = 25 #simulation for tf seconds
n = 1000 #number of evaluation points
dt = tf/n
T = np.linspace(0.0, tf, n+1)

state0 = ([np.pi/4, 0.2]) #this is the initial state

sol = integrate.solve_ivp(der_state, (0, tf), state0, t_eval=T)
ang_pos = sol.y[0]
```

When running the code, the following error shows up:

```
      3         der = np.zeros_like(state)
      4         der[0] = state[1]
----> 5         der[1] = (-(g/L)*np.sin(state[0]))-((k/m1)*((np.sin(state[0])-(np.sin(state[2])))))
      6         der[2] = state[3]
      7         der[3] = (-(g/L)*np.sin(state[0]))-((k/m2)*((np.sin(state[2])-(np.sin(state[1])))))

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

I do not seem to understand what is causing this issue.

Comment: Your indices are wrong, you put a derivative where you want a position, and in the gravity term there is a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue happens because of the following line of code:

```
state0 = ([np.pi/4, 0.2])
```

`state0` holds the following list of **size** 2:

```
[0.7853981633974483, 0.2]
```

You then call `integrate.solve_ivp` with `state0`:

```
sol = integrate.solve_ivp(der_state, (0, tf), state0, t_eval=T)
```

Within the `der_state` function, the `state` variable - which is `state0` - is expected to have **more than two** items in it:

```
der[1] = (-(g/L)*np.sin(state[0]))-((k/m1)*((np.sin(state[0])-(np.sin(state[2]))))) # Indexing 3 item in state
der[2] = state[3] # Indexing 4 item in state
der[3] = (-(g/L)*np.sin(state[0]))-((k/m2)*((np.sin(state[2])-(np.sin(state[1]))))) # Indexing 3 and 2 item in state
```

That is why you get the following error:

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Comment: Or in short, as a unit test run `print(der_state(0,state0))` when the ingredients are all available.